# How to set up postfix to download incoming mesages from another server via IMAP?

Tags: email, postfix, imap

How can I set -up a postfix-based mail server so that it will not only receie messages incoming via SMTP, but also act actively and download (via IMAP) messages from another server if there are any there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You use [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) for that.